# Clearsigned file isn't valid in ubuntu xenial

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet, lan

I got a problem, when I tried to apt-get update it gives me these error. I don't know why, but I got my network properly work in other way. Please help fix it. I tried many methods of fixing it according to what I've searched but it never worked.

```
root@isaac-desktop:~# dpkg --configure -a
root@isaac-desktop:~# apt-get update
Get:1 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [392 B]
Get:2 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [392 B]
Get:3 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [392 B]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [392 B]
Err:1 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:2 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:3 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Fetched 2,059 B in 1s (1,863 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Do other websites work when this is occurring?

Comment: @user535733: This linked question isn't helpful because it was closed as off topic.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX wget -S -O - 'http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease' 2>&1 | head -n 30`? Thanks.